# Please, someone know why I can't save data inside the vector in R?

Tags: r

```
checknames <- function(){
gamers <- c("Rebeca","Lucas","Mario")
games <- c("3","1","3")
scores <- c("200","100","205")
table <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores)
r=0
repeat{
 print("Name Player 1: ")
 name1=scan(,what="character",1)
 for(i in 1:length(gamers)){
   if(name1==gamers[i]){
     print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
     r=scan(,what="character",1)
   }
 }
 if(r==2){
   break
 }
 if(r==0){
   gamers=c(gamers,name1)
   name1 <- data.frame(gamers=name1,games="0",scores="100")
   table1 <- rbind(table,name1)
   print("Nice")
   break
 }
}
}
checknames()
```

Hi, I created vectors with gamers, games, and scores, and I want to ask the user a name, and if this name is not in the vector, I want to add this new name to the vector, but I can´t save this and I don´t know why.
If anyone knows it, I will thank it forever :)

Comment: I see a couple of minor issues, but the main thing you're alluding to is probably in the line that says `table1 <- rbind(table,name1)` - are you sure you don't want to assign the new table to `table` instead of `table1`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some changes to your code:

1. Create your table outside your function unless the table is used inside the function only.
2. For number of games and score it is a good approach to use numbers not strings.
3. You don't have to loop through your table to check if a given name is already there.
4. Return your new data table.
5. Cast your function with the table as argument. Assign the function to your table to save the changes.

```r
tbl_game <- data.frame(gamers = c("Rebeca","Lucas","Mario"),
                       games  = c(3, 1, 3),        # number of games not as string
                       scores = c(200, 100, 205))  # score not as string

checknames <- function(my_tbl){
  r <- 0
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 1: ")
    name1  <- scan(,what="character",1)
    if (name1 %in% my_tbl$gamers) {  # check if name is in table
      print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
      r <- scan(,what="character",1)
    }
    if(r==2){
      return(my_tbl)  # Return data with no changes
    }
    if(r==0){
      new_entry <- data.frame(gamers=name1, games=0, scores=100)
      my_tbl <- rbind(my_tbl, new_entry)
      print("Nice")
      return(my_tbl)  # Return data with new entry
    }
  }
}

checknames(tbl_game)  # perhaps assign it to tbl_game
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing well in adding the name to the dataframe. 
If you want to have the result available after executing the function you have to call the table again at the end of the function.

```
checknames <- function(){
    code here
    table1 #to be returned
}
newTable <- checknames()
```